# Catch Nil Error in If/Else

Tags: swift, try-catch

While this seems beyond simple to me, I cannot seem to figure out how to code this. I am trying to write an if/else if/else statement, but it's not working. Here's what I have:

```
for value in values {
  if Float(value) > 0 {
    print("positive")
  } else if value == "N/A" {
    print("not available")
  } else {
    print("negative")
  }
}
```

Values is an array of strings, where the value is either "1.0", "N/A", or "-1.0". Through array iteration, if it hits "N/A", it throws an error. I feel like I need to embed this in a try/catch block. It's catching a nil error. Thanks!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you show how your values array looks like?

Comment: Wow, the code snippet I included had one small change: for my else if, I printed "not available", but in my real code i had "return", so that was cancelling out the rest of my function. Thanks for all the help & comments though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for value in values {
    if let val = Float(value) {
        if val > 0 {
            print("positive")
        } else {
            print("negative")
        }
    } else {
        print("not available")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this array

```
let values = ["1", "-2", "N/A"]
```

you can write

```
for value in values {
    guard let number = Float(value) else {
        print("N/A")
        continue
    }
    switch number {
    case 0: print("zero")
    case _ where number < 0: print("negative")
    case _ where number > 0: print("postive")
    default: fatalError()
    }
}
```

and this is the output

```
postive
negative
N/A
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
 let values = ["1", "-2", "N/A"]
 for value in values 
 {
     print( 
            Float(value) == nil ? "not available" :
            Float(value)! > 0   ? "positive"      
                                : "negative" 
          )
 }
```